# Streaming Pictures (local network only) to the new AppleTV

Tags: appletv, privacy, streaming

How-To stream and/or upload Pictures (local network only, I don't wish any cloud) to the new AppleTV? With a web search I found a few Apps, but they are discontinued.

I am aware of AirPlay, but search for a more native way.

Comment: Apple wants you to put your photos in iCloud and access them from there.  Any reason this does not work for you?  Also why will Airplay not do?

Answer (score 1):

The native way to stream pictures via local network only to an AppleTV is via AirPlay.

You cannot natively upload pictures to the AppleTV via local network only. You will require a third party app for that, or the use of iCloud.

Comment: and this? View photos from your Mac on Apple TV https://support.apple.com/guide/tv/view-photos-from-your-mac-atvb9b305fb0/tvos But sadly it does not work for me.

Comment: Yes, that's also a way of streaming photos - but it requires you to have a Mac and that they're on the same local network. That is not required with the method I gave as an answer.